# Error using init command on cleverstack

Tags: node.js

I'm running cleverstack.io framework on windows 8.1, when I run the command:

```
$ clever init my-app
```

The following error outputs:

```
events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
Error: spawn ENOENT
    at errnoException (child_process.js:988:11)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:779:34)
```

The cleverstack framework installs with no error messages, then I assume that was installed correctly.

Comment: Something is wrong, It cant find something it was trying to execute as a child process.

Answer (score 0):

This bug was fixed in the 1.0.0 release of cleverstack-cli, please see [the release](https://github.com/CleverStack/cleverstack-cli/releases/tag/1.0.0) and [this pull request](https://github.com/CleverStack/cleverstack-cli/pull/7) for more information about the release and what has changed.

Run the following command to install the latest version of cleverstack-cli

```
npm install -g cleverstack-cli
```

Once you have installed the latest version of the CleverStack CLI, run the init command again

```
clever init my-app
```

Once the command has finished running, to start your application run the following

```
cd my-app
clever serve

// Visit http://localhost:9000 to see your new application
```